# Transitive dependency problem with Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

We recently updated a deprecated package in one of our projects replacing it (as directed) with

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="4.0.0" />`

This has a dependency for `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs >= 3.0.32` We also use the package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask version 2.8.1` which has a dependency on `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs >= 3.0.31` (.NetCoreApp version 3.1). The DurableTask can be updated to `version 2.9.0` but this does not upgrade the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` which is still listed as `>= 3.0.31`

We are getting errors & when setting up the CosmosClient consistently get the following error:

```
error CS1705: ... uses 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.32.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host' with identity 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.31.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

How can I force the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` package to use `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs >= 3.0.32` even though its dependency states `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs >= 3.0.31` which I believe means lowest available .31 or over.

We don't really want to undo the previous package update as that would mean using a deprecated package again.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` with newwer version explicitly:

```bash
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs --version 3.0.33
```

Or by changing the .csproj

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.33" />
```

Comment: We had done that with 3.0.32 & it had no affect. I did try 3.0.33 also & the same error happens. I think this is because the >= 3.0.31 will accept the 31 version by default as it is the lowest version available that it can have.

Comment: @onesixtyfourth how do you build the project? When exactly this error happens? Can you add a [mre] somewhere?

Comment: I am afraid I can't add any examples for you. Work place rules. Builds locally in vs2022 runs locally against Azurite & Azure Cosmos emulator. The error above is produced in the projects start up file when `CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClientBuilder( ...)` is called. I have to put a watch on cosmosClient to see it.